# Javascript filter array in console log with ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get arrays from the `Data` that are:

1. filtered by John
2. filtered by Mack
3. sorted by AccountNumber
4. filtered by Jane and sorted by number ascending

```js
Data= [
{
  AccountNumber: "Abc 123",
  name: "John"
},
{
  AccountNumber: "DCS 231",
  name: "Jane"
},
{
  AccountNumber: "LMK 456",
  name: "Mack"
},
{
  AccountNumber: "JSF 789",
  name: "Alice"
}
];

number= {
  "Abc 123": 234,
  "DCS 231": 1233,
  "LMK 456": 534543,
  "JSF 789": 543532
};
```

I have achieved this so far but not getting the last two one **sorted by AccountNumber** and **filtered by Alice; sorted by balance ascending**

```
let John = Data.filter(username => {
  return username.name === 'john';
})
console.log(John); 

let Mack = Data.filter(username => {
  return username.name === 'mack';
})
console.log(Mack);
```

Comment: what is the value of `John` in number object. Is it account number? If so is it number or string? because I see that in `Data` object account number is string

Comment: so the `AccountNumber: "DCS 231"` is a reference to number object? so the `AccountNumber` is `1233`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a sort function to sort array of object like this:

**For filtered by Jane; sorted by number ascending:**

```js
var Data= [
{
 "AccountNumber": "Abc 123",
  "name": "John"
},
{
  "AccountNumber": "DCS 231",
  "name": "Jane"
},
{
  "AccountNumber": "LMK 456",
  "name": "Mack"
},
{
  "AccountNumber": "JSF 789",
  "name": "Alice"
}
];

var Alice= Data.filter(function (username , index) 
{
    return username.name === 'Alice';
})
.sort(function (a, b) 
{
    if(a.AccountNumber < b.AccountNumber) { return -1; }
    if(a.AccountNumber > b.AccountNumber) { return 1; }
});
console.log(Alice);
```

**For sorted by AccountNumber :**

change `return username.name === 'Alice';` to `return username;`

Comment: the 4th point (filtered by Jane; sorted by number ascending) i want to both value filter by name and the number with that account Object. Match the number object and the Data array name and want to show them in console

Answer (score 0):

To sort by account number:

Data.sort((a, b) => a.AccountNumber.localeCompare(b.AccountNumber));

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```js
const someData = [
  {
    AccountNumber: "Abc 123",
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    AccountNumber: "DCS 231",
    name: "Jane"
  },
  {
    AccountNumber: "zxy 321",
    name: "Alice"
  },
  {
    AccountNumber: "LMK 456",
    name: "Mack"
  },
  {
    AccountNumber: "JSF 789",
    name: "Alice"
  }
];

const someNumbers = {
  "Abc 123": 234,
  "DCS 231": 1233,
  "LMK 456": 534543,
  "JSF 789": 543532,
  "zxy 321": 12
};

const filterByName = (arr, name) => arr.filter(el => el.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase());

const compareByAccountNumber = (a, b) => {
  const accountA = a.AccountNumber.toUpperCase();
  const accountB = b.AccountNumber.toUpperCase();
  
  let output = 0
  if (accountA < accountB) { output = -1; }
  if (accountA > accountB) { output = 1; }

  return output;
}

const compareByAmount = (a, b) => {
  const amountA = someNumbers[a];
  const amountB = someNumbers[b];

  return amountA - amountB;
}

const filteredByJohn = filterByName(someData, 'john');
const filteredByMack = filterByName(someData, 'mack');
const filteredByAlice = filterByName(someData, 'alice');

const sortedByAccountNumber = someData.slice(0).sort(compareByAccountNumber);

const aliceAccountNames = filteredByAlice.slice(0).map(account => account.AccountNumber);
const numberKeysSortedByAmount = Object.keys(someNumbers).sort(compareByAmount)
const filteredByAliceSortedByNumber = []


numberKeysSortedByAmount.forEach(numKey => {
  if(aliceAccountNames.includes(numKey)) {
    const accountObj = someData.filter(el => el.AccountNumber.toLowerCase() === numKey.toLowerCase())
    filteredByAliceSortedByNumber.push(accountObj)
  }
})


console.group('::::[ FANCY TITLE ]::::')
console.log('filtered by john: ', filteredByJohn)
console.log('filtered by mack: ', filteredByMack)
console.log('sorted by AccountNumber: ', sortedByAccountNumber)
console.log('filtered by Alice; sorted by number ascending: ', filteredByAliceSortedByNumber)
console.groupEnd()
```